# How to return to the previous codes after using the cscope to, like, find a definition of a function in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, cscope

How to return to the previous position after using the cscope to, like, find a definition of a function in Emacs? Since I wanna continue reading the following codes after I get to know the definitions of some functions.

Comment: You should give a little bit more details about your setup so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to:  (ring-insert find-tag-marker-ring (point-marker))  before invoking cscope.

I have this:

```
(defun mmc-find-tag(&optional prefix)
  "union of `find-tag' alternatives. decides upon major-mode"
  (interactive "P")
  (if (and (boundp 'cscope-minor-mode)
           cscope-minor-mode)
  (progn
    (ring-insert find-tag-marker-ring (point-marker))
;; (push-tag-mark)
    (setq cscope-display-cscope-buffer prefix)
    (call-interactively
     (if prefix
         'cscope-find-this-symbol
       'cscope-find-global-definition-no-prompting
       )))
(call-interactively 'find-tag)))

(substitute-key-definition 'find-tag 'mmc-find-tag global-map)
```